# Determine complexity for a recursive function

Tags: asymptotic-complexity, recurrence

I have a problem in determining the recurrence relations of the following code:

```
 public static void Method1(String S){ 
  if(S.length()>1){      
  System.out.print(S.charAt(S.length()-1));  
  Method1(S.substring(1,S.length()-1));
  System.out.print(S.charAt(0)); 
  } 
  if(S.length()==1) 
  System.out.print(S.charAt(0));
 }
```

I understand that this code reverses the given string  and the terminating condition is when the string.length()=0 but I can't understand how to determine the recurrence relation and complexity. what steps should I consider to solve this kinds of questions

Answer (score 0):

You could simply rewrite it as iterative, which shouldn't change the complexity. Anyhow, consider a single call of the recursive function:

### What is its complexity excluding recursive calls?

There are two calls to `print()` with the first and last character, or the only one in case of the terminating call. The complexity of that is probably constant. Further, there is a `substring()` call for the parameter to the recursive call. This call is probably linear, but it could also be constant, it depends on the implementation.

### Then, how many recursive calls are there per call?

There is exactly one recursive call, making this pretty simple.

### Further, how deep will this recurse?

Each call gives two less characters to the succeeding one, so the number of recursive calls is linear to the input length.

### Summary

For the overall complexity, you only multiply the different steps with each other to get the overall complexity. In this case, it's pretty lousy concerning what the function does.

Comment: so is the recurrence relation
CN=C(N-2)+2

C0=0

Comment: I don't understand where `+2` comes from. Also, you forgot `C1`.